# Unable to resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, build.gradle, thymeleaf

I'm just learning how to work with spring and I'm new in this. I tried to add thymeleaf to my project with Gradle dependency but It can not be resolved. I think my way of adding thymeleaf to project is wrong. What should i do?
This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE')
}
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group 'com.aminsl'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
   compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.9.RELEASE'
   compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
}
```

Comment: You need to add the dependency plugin next to the spring boot plugin.

Comment: Also `spring-webmvc` is part of the `spring-boot-starter-web` for the latter you should remove the `version` that will then be managed by the dependency plugin.

Comment: The Gradle script looks good, check your application.properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would go to https://start.spring.io/, select the dependencies I need as shown below:

[image]

And then Generate the project.

Using the website gives me the below gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Looks like you are missing the right plugins in your build file.